# Updating docker registry in ubuntu 14.0

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to upgrade my docker registry to version 2 on a ubuntu box.

This is what I did so far :

1) Bought up a v2 registry container up on the same host (ubuntu) where my v1 registry was running.

2) Executed this  command:

docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e V1_REGISTRY=v1.registry.fqdn -e V2_REGISTRY=v2.registry.fqdn docker/migrator

And I got this error:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

The docker daemon IS running on this host though, and I can do a docker info and get the right output .

I also did a ps -ef |grep docker and saw the process running

oot      5742     1  3 Dec01 ?        03:32:47 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376

SO I don't understand why this error shows up .

Comment: So I think my docker daemon is not using a socket. It's using tcp. How can I alter my upgrade docker command accordingly?

Comment: Does ` /var/run/docker.sock` exist? Are you in the `docker` group? Sure you don't need to use `sudo`?